# Average Case Time Complexity Analysis of Binary Counter Increment

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, average

I am attempting to find the average case time complexity, not amortized analysis, of a binary counter. As I am not entirely confident in my time complexity analyzing skills, I would like to confirm that my average case analysis of the pseudocode provided below is correct.

Let *k* be the length of the array.

```
Increment(Array)
    i = 0
    while i < k and Array[i] == 1
        Array[i] = o
        i = i + 1
    if i < k
        Array[i] = 1
```

In order to find the average time taken, I find the average amount of bits flipped per run. As a result, I found this to be *O(2+k/(2^k))*, which equals *O(1)* for a large *k*.

Is this the correct average case running time? If not, how would I begin to approach this problem?

Comment: If you really do mean [average-case time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average-case_complexity), then you will need a probability distribution of inputs to the algorithm.  What distribution are you using?

Comment: I am assuming each input has the same probability to occur.

Comment: With a uniform distribution, the algebra for the average-case analysis and the aggregate amortized analysis are virtually the same (the aggregate analysis skips dividing by `n`).  In particular the summed series is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am assuming each input has the same probability to occur

This means that each bit is independently on or off with probability 1/2.

The [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) is the relevant distribution for the complexity: you flip coins, and end the experiment on the first tail outcome (there is nothing further to carry).

The mean of the geometric distribution here is exactly 2 (see above link, or derive it from basic principles), so the average complexity is indeed *O(1)*.