# Average case of binary counter

Tags: algorithm, binary, counter, analysis

```
INCREMENT(A)
i = 0
while i< A.length and A[i] ==1
    A[i]=0
    i=i+1
if i< A.length
    A[i]=1
```

I am now studying amortized analysis by myself and I am thinking of the differences between average case analysis and amortized analysis that I know that the amortized cost of the binary counter operation, INCREMENT(Array), is O(1) but what if I want to analyze the average case of the INCREMENT? I am thinking of assuming the average amount of bits that we need to flip is n/2 where n is the total amount of bits, but I saw the answer in [Average Case Time Complexity Analysis of Binary Counter Increment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40570866/average-case-time-complexity-analysis-of-binary-counter-increment), which does not make much sense to me. Can anyone please explain? This will be helpful because I really what to know the answer:D

Comment: You're confusing the **average number of bits that are on** with the **average number of consecutive bits that are on**.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that "average" means that we pick a random array of 0 and 1 of length `n` with equal probability to choose each possible option. It's equivalent to setting each of `n` elements of the array to `0` with probability 1/2 and to `1` with the same probability.

What is the probability that the body of the while loop will be executed at least once? It is 1/2 (it is executed if and only if the first element of the array is 1). What is the probability that the body of the loop is executed at least twice? It is the probability that the first two element are equal to 1, which is equal to 1/2 * 1/2 = 1/4 (as the probabilities that the first and the second elements are equal to one are independent). We can show by induction that the probability that the body of the while loop is executed at least `i` times (`1 <= i <= n`) is `(1/2)^n`.

It means that it will do one iteration with probability 1/2, one more iteration with probability 1/4, one more iteration with probability 1/8 and so on. Thus, the expected value of the number of iterations is `sum for 1 <= i <= n (1/2)^i`, which is bounded above by the sum of infinite series `1/2+1/4+1/8+...`, which is equal to 1 (it's clearly a constant). All other operations except for the while loop are executed constant number of times regardless of the input. Thus, the total time complexity is constant on average.